# Java: Trouble with wildcards/generics

Tags: java, javabeans, supercsv, unbounded-wildcard

I am really struggling with using wildcards/generics. I'm trying to create a `FileManager` utility class that can accept custom Java Beans and write read/write the bean to a file. Just to give an example imagine I have an interface called `Data` that is implemented by `RecipeData` and `DemographicData`. I'm using `Super CSV` to convert a CSV file to a Java Bean. Here is my read method which is based on tutorial code I found from `Super CSV`.

```
public interface Data { method declarations }
public class RecipeData implements Data { class stuff goes here }
public class DemographicData implements Data { class stuff goes here }

final public class FileManager {
    public static void parseCsvFile(String filename, CellProcessor[] processors, String[] nameMappings, List<? extends Data> container) { 
        ICsvBeanReader beanReader = null;
        try {
            beanReader = new CsvBeanReader(new FileReader(filename), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

            Data data;
            while((data = beanReader.read(Data.class, nameMappings, processors)) != null ) {
                container.add(data);
            }
        } finally {
            if (beanReader != null) {
                beanReader.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, I'm getting the following error:

> The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Data) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (Data)

I'm not sure what I'm doing is even possible. The idea is, that the `container` that is passed can be of type `RecipeData` or `DemographicData`. So I think one problem is that `data` should be of those two types.

Can anyone give feedback on how I could potentially fix this or if it'll even work?

EDIT:
I'm really not sure this is possible.

Comment: In your generic you said `extends` - it should instead be `Data` since both  `RecipeData` and `DemographicData` implement and NOT extends the `Data` interface. This way, you use "interface as a type" pattern. By the way, you can please show where you call `writeToCsvFile` to see what you are passing to the function?

Comment: Also have a look at the PECS principle as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super). Summary: If you only want to add elements to the collection, use `Collection<? super Data>`.

Comment: Hi, I'm pretty sure you use extends regardless of whether it is a class or interface that is being used. The 'nameMappings' and 'processors' work fine. I've tested it considerably on a non-generic write function so that is not the problem. As far as the 'container' I pass, it is declared in another class as 'List<Data> container = new ArrayList<RecipeData>();'

Comment: @RobinKrahl that did fix my error. I will test it as soon as I can.

Comment: @AlexCauthen So `container` is a `List<RecipeData>`, but the bean reader could return a `DemographicData` that you want to add to the list.  Do you see the potential problem?

Comment: If I pass a 'List<RecipeData>' I would expect it to return that. If I pass a 'List<DemographicData>' I would expect it to return that. I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I'm trying to make this as a generic csv parser for any Bean.

Comment: @AlexCauthen Ah, I thought the reader could always return both `RecipeData` and `DemographicData`. Then ignore my second comment.

Comment: But I can't get it to work, and I'm not sure that it is even possible in the manner that I am trying to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a wildcard for `List<? extends Data> container`, use `List<Data> container`.

Comment: Your answer would be more informative if you explained why that works.